# How to implement a horizontally-scrolling collection view with a header on top?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to have a collection view that scrolls horizontally, but I also want it to have a header on top of and to the right. I've tried implementing this as I would a vertically-scrolling collection view, and the header ends up to the left of the first cell.

Here is how I dequeue the header:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let header = dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! HeaderView
        header.setWidth(to: headerWidth)
        return header
    }
```

Size of the header:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 12)
    }
```

Apart from that, the only other properties I initialize are the scroll direction and insets of the collection view

Comment: show your code atleast

Comment: I used different view for header and `didEndDisplaying cell:`.

Comment: to have horizontal , set scrollDirection of collection  to horizontol

Comment: That means you don't need a header for every section I think, so just put a UILabel above collectionView should achieve your desire.

Answer (score 0):

Headers positions : are in the **Top** of the section in case of scrolling vertically and in the **left** of the section in case of horizontally scrolling , So it's normal that it's showing in the left of the section in your case .

If you want to display your `reusable view` in the right of every section You can use **UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter** instead .

But if you want to display your `reusable view` between every section , You can set the size of header view in the very first section to .zero .

You can manipulate in every header view size with `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` function like so:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        if section == 0 {
            return .zero
        }
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 12)
    }
```

In this case i removed (technically not removed but hide) the first header in the left , Which is in the first section , But you can set the size for every header .

Comment: I don't have sections. This is just one horizontally scrolling collection view.

Comment: The reason why I can't just add the header view as a regular view and constrain it on top of the collection view, is because for various reasons I am constraining multiple collection views on top of each other and don't want to insert "artificial" header views between each one

Comment: I don't think you can register header and constraints it at the top in case of horizontally scrolling ,But you can play around it , Like if is there an vertically collection view on top of your horizontally scrolling collection view , You can add a `Footer` to the top collection and make it the top header of the bottom horizontally collection view , Otherwise ,You can add a regular view as subview to the collection view and constraint on top of your collection view .